# Convert a pandas DataFrame to parquet in memory and load it to Hadoop in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I have a pandas Dataframe(not very large, can be easily stored in memory), and I want to convert it to parquet and load it to Hadoop without having to store it locally first.

Currently, I am converting the dataframe in parquet format and saving it locally. Then I read it from my local files and upload it to Hadoop.

I do not know how to convert the dataframe to  parquet, I just know this piece of code which takes the dataframe and save it in parquet format locally:

```
df = pandas.dataFrame()
table = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df)
parquet.write_table(table, "df.parquet")
```

I just want to upload df to Hadoop in parquet format. Is there a way to do that?